# Перегрузка оператора сравнения для сортировки массива структур С++

Tags: c++, сортировка, структуры

```
struct doc {
    int n;
    int sr;
};
```

`vector <doc> d;`v
как перегрузить оператор сравнения для сортировки вектора  d по полю sr через std::sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно перегрузить оператор сравнения для пользовательского типа, а можно и не перегружать.
Функция [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) имеет перегрузку, в которой можно в качестве параметра передать [функтор(функцию сравнения)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare). С помощью лямбды-функции ваш код будет достаточно простым и понятным

```
sort(d.begin(), d.end(), 
    [](const doc& a, const doc& b) -> bool
{ 
    return a.sr < b.sr; 
});
```

Функция компаратор возращает true, если первый элемент меньше второго

Answer (score 0):

Вот так например:

```
bool operator < (const doc & left, const doc & right)
{
     return left.sr < right.sr;
}
```

Такое решение обеспечивает сортировку "по-умолчанию", что, в прочем, покрывает 80% ситуаций когда требуется сортировка.

Comment: А как это позволит сравнивать два элемента типа `doc`?

Comment: Семен Семеныч! Никак конечно.